# mod_python not working correctly

Tags: django, ubuntu, apache2, mod-python

I recently installed mod_python to use with Apache2. But, instead of displaying a python page, it asks me to download it. I followed the instructions here:
http://www.howtoforge.com/embedding-python-in-apache2-with-mod_python-debian-etch

When I restart apache2:
 * Restarting web server apache2                                               [Tue Jul 12 21:00:44 2011] [warn] module python_module is already loaded, skipping
 ... waiting [Tue Jul 12 21:00:45 2011] [warn] module python_module is already loaded, skipping

What's wrong?

Oh, and do I need to enable the psp handler for Django? Is it not required for the templates?

Comment: Belongs on [sf]. Also consider using mod_wsgi instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't follow random directions on the internet. Follow the [actual documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/) on Django's website.
2. Don't use mod_python - it's deprecated. Use mod_wsgi.
3. Don't even think about PSP.

Comment: I installed mod_wsgi, and apache still asks to download python files.